# how to detect element changes on selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

what i want to accomplish is detect first the changes on the div(ng-repeat) list  which is is the result of a search query and click the first result ,but my problem is the click event are already firing and selecting the already listed item which is must be the result the search

Search event

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/ul[2]/li[1]/div/input")).sendKeys(fname);
```

Click Event

```
 WebDriverWait dList = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        dList.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"top-menu-members\"]/div[1]/div")));
```

here is the div listing

```html
<div class="list cursor-pointer ng-scope" ng-mouseenter="memberEntered(member)" ng-mouseleave="memberLeft(member)" ng-repeat="member in (members | orderBy:['-new','firstname'])" ng-hide="member.id == user.id" ng-init="member.name = member.firstname + ' ' + member.lastname;" ng-if="members.length">
                                        <div class="settings pull-left blue" ng-click="selectMemberSubmenu(member); moveSubmenu($event, 2);">
                                            <a href="#" ng-class="{ 'open': member.id == selectedMember.id }">
                                                <i class="fa fa-caret-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <a ui-sref="members.task({ id: member.id })" ng-click="markAsSeen('member', member, $event, false)" href="/members/7E1C4A77-C29A-4121-B305-8766340F4DDA">
                                            <div class="profpic members pull-left">
                                                <div class="bg-image" style="background-image: url(/img/avatar-man.png)"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info pull-left">
                                                <p class="pull-left ng-binding">Kyben Jal</p>
                                                <p class="pull-left role ng-binding">Company Manager</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- ngIf: member.new --><div class="member-circle pull-right ng-scope" ng-if="member.new" ng-click="markAsSeen('member', member, $event)">
                                                <img src="/img/notif.png">
                                            </div><!-- end ngIf: member.new -->
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Actually your question is not clear...Please would you explain more with HTML as well..

Comment: there is already a listed div item, what i want to do is the click must only triggered after the new listed of item is already been set which is the result of the search query, but apparently the click event  already firing up  and clicking the first set of lists item instead of the new set

Comment: Could you share HTML as well

Comment: Do you want to until search text present in the list, then select that element from the list???